# Python Recursive Sudoku Solver Doesn't Return the Solution

Tags: python, numpy, sudoku

I tried to optimize [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_UYXzGuqvM) code and my final code was as shown below

```python
import numpy as np
sudoku = np.array([[0, 9, 0, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0, 8],
                   [0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 0, 3, 5, 0],
                   [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 4],
                   [0, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6],
                   [6, 3, 0, 2, 0, 8, 0, 4, 5],
                   [7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 9, 0, 0],
                   [9, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1],
                   [0, 4, 8, 0, 2, 7, 0, 0, 0],
                   [5, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 0, 3, 0]])

#Checking if the number (n) can be placed there (row, col)
def check(sudoku, row, col, n):
    # Row check
    if np.sum(sudoku[row,:] == n) != 0: return False;
    # Col check
    if np.sum(sudoku[:,col] == n) != 0: return False;
    # Sqr check
    row0, col0 = (row//3)*3, (col//3)*3
    if np.sum(sudoku[row0:row0+3,col0:col0+3] == n) != 0: return False;
    return True

def solve_sudoku(sudoku):
    rows, cols = np.where(sudoku == 0)
    for row in rows:
        for col in cols:
            for num in range(1, 10):
                if check(sudoku, row, col, num):
                    sudoku[row, col] = num
                    solve_sudoku(sudoku)
                    sudoku[row, col] = 0
            return
    print(sudoku)
    return sudoku

solved = solve_sudoku(sudoku)
```

My problem is that even though the solution is successfully printed as shown below, the variable **solved** is just a NoneType and stores nothing.

```python
[[3 9 7 4 5 2 6 1 8]
 [8 6 4 7 1 9 3 5 2]
 [2 1 5 8 3 6 7 9 4]
 [4 8 1 5 9 3 2 7 6]
 [6 3 9 2 7 8 1 4 5]
 [7 5 2 1 6 4 9 8 3]
 [9 7 3 6 4 5 8 2 1]
 [1 4 8 3 2 7 5 6 9]
 [5 2 6 9 8 1 4 3 7]]
```

[TL;DR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6T8w.png) The function prints the solution but returns nothing. What should I do to store the printed solution?

Comment: You need to use the result of your recursive call to `solve_sudoku` and check whether the game is finished at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours, I came up with this solution. **solved** stores the solution now.

```python
import numpy as np
sudoku = np.array([[0, 9, 0, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0, 8],
                   [0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 0, 3, 5, 0],
                   [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 4],
                   [0, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6],
                   [6, 3, 0, 2, 0, 8, 0, 4, 5],
                   [7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 9, 0, 0],
                   [9, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1],
                   [0, 4, 8, 0, 2, 7, 0, 0, 0],
                   [5, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 0, 3, 0]])
solved = np.zeros_like(sudoku)

def check(arg, row, col, n):
    if np.sum(arg[row,:] == n) != 0: return False;
    if np.sum(arg[:,col] == n) != 0: return False;
    row0, col0 = (row//3)*3, (col//3)*3
    if np.sum(arg[row0:row0+3,col0:col0+3] == n) != 0: return False;
    return True

def solve_sudoku(arg):
    global solved
    rows, cols = np.where(arg == 0)
    for row in rows:
        for col in cols:
            for num in range(1, 10):
                if check(arg, row, col, num):
                    arg[row, col] = num
                    solve_sudoku(arg)
                    arg[row, col] = 0
            return
    solved = arg.copy()
solve_sudoku(sudoku)
```

I don't know if it it is the best way to optimize the code, feedbacks are welcomed.

Comment: It's a bad idea to use global state like this. It's brittle (variable name changes break the function), it's non-reentrant, in a large codebase it'd be a nightmare if a bug occurred to figure out which functions messing with global state have done what when. Better to return the solution up the call stack so all modifications to state are completely internal to the function.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this code:

```
if check(sudoku, row, col, num):
    sudoku[row, col] = num
    solve_sudoku(sudoku)
    sudoku[row, col] = 0  # undo this move
```

If the Sudoku is solvable, a `solve_sudoku(sudoku)` call will eventually find the solution. When you get your solution, you should immediately stop backtracking using `return`. Otherwise, the next line `sudoku[row, col] = 0` will undo the solution you found and further iterations keep trying the next possible numbers. Since Sudoku has only one solution, checking more numbers after finding a solution is not necessary. You may just return a true value to end the recursion.

For example, you may code like this:

```
if solve_sudoku(sudoku):
    return True
```

or

```
if solve_sudoku(sudoku):
    return sudoku
```

This prevents `sudoku[row, col] = 0` from erasing the solution and ultimately returns the solved grid to the initial caller after the recursive call stack unwinds.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here in your code:

```
                    solve_sudoku(sudoku)
                    sudoku[row, col] = 0
            return
```

In the first line, you recur, but you ignore the return value, which discards any return value from that call and all recursions below it.

In the last line, you return the default value on `None`.  Either of these kills your continuity of recursion return values.

Answer (score 0):

The `print(sudoku)` call is happening when `solve_sudoku` is called with a completely-filled Sudoku array (one without any remaining zeroes), not in the top-level recursive call.

Each time `solve_sudoku` is called with an incomplete Sudoku array, you are testing each number between one and ten in the upper-leftmost zero-filled cell, and if the number can be placed in the cell, you place it there, attempt to solve the rest of the grid, and then set the cell back to zero. Once you do this for each number between one and ten, you return `None`, which is why you are seeing `None` returned from the top-level `solve_sudoku` call.

Answer (score 0):

```
def check(grid, num, x, y):
    for i in range(9):
        if grid[i][y] == num:
            return False
    for j in range(9):
        if grid[x][j] == num:
            return False
    x0 = (x//3) * 3
    y0 = (y//3) * 3
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if grid[x0+i][y0+j] == num:
                return False
    return True

def solve(grid):
    for i in range(9 + 1):
        if i==9:
            return True
        for j in range(9):
            if grid[i][j] == 0:
                for num in range(1,10):
                    if check(grid, num, i, j):
                        grid[i][j] = num
                        if solve(grid):
                            return True
                        grid[i][j] = 0
                return False
```

This should work for you. It does not return the array but modifies it. So if you pass

```
solve(sudoku_grid)
```

and then print sudoku_grid it will give you the solved output